# Dont understand the function of cmd_data(ii) = cell2mat(textscan(char(data{i}(ALL_STRT(ii):(ALL_STRT(ii)+4))),'%f')); at all

Tags: matlab

```
IND_STRT = 0;
ALL_STRT = IND_STRT:12:510;
cmd_data = zeros(length(ALL_STRT),1);  %example: x=zeros(1,21) gives you a 1 by 21 matrix
for ii = 1:length(ALL_STRT) %declare variable ii to run from the row of length 
    if ~isempty(data{i})
        cmd_data(ii) = cell2mat(textscan(char(data{i}(ALL_STRT(ii):(ALL_STRT(ii)+4))),'%f'));
    end
end
```

I need to read the EPS from EnduroSat, however i have difficulty understanding the line cmd_data(ii) = cell2mat(textscan(char(data{i}(ALL_STRT(ii):(ALL_STRT(ii)+4))),'%f'));
Im required to utilised MatLab to code and this particular line have an error and i don't understand why.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. Explaining pieces of code you pulled of the internet is outside the scope of this site, alas. Either ask the author of this code, the one requiring you to use this code, or read up on the documentation of `cell2mat`, `textscan` and `char`.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you see a complicated line like this in MATLAB, try to break it up.

```
% find some indices. These values have been selected by the programmer/data, can't say why.
a=ALL_STRT(ii):(ALL_STRT(ii)+4)
% obtain that articular section of the data
b=data{i}(a)
% convert it to a char data type (characters)
c=char(b)
% scan text, and treat them as float 
d=textscan(c,'%f')
% the output is a cell array, we want a matrix instead. Make the cell array into a matrix.
cmd_data(ii) = cell2mat(d)
```

You can read particularly what each of these do better in their documentation pages, and you can see it work if you put a break-point in the code, and see what each of this parts output when you call it. Learn how to debug, is a very very powerful tool